# Get current timestamp in microseconds since epoch?

Tags: c++, timestamp, c++-chrono

I have a below code from which we are trying to get current timestamp in microseconds since epoch time but we are using `steady_clock`.

```
inline uint64_t get_timestamp()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> ts = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(ts.time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```

Is this the right way to do that since as per my understanding `steady_clock` is used to measure the passage of time not to get the current time of day? Or should I use `system_clock` for this like as shown below:

```
inline uint64_t get_timestamp()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> ts = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(ts.time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```

I need to use [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) package only since that's what all our code is using.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::uint64_t`? At least for a bit longer, anyways. Current time since epoch is 1440440480 seconds at the time of this writing, which is 0x51dac207a0000 microseconds.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `uint64_t` ...

Comment: Sorry guys confused with nanoseconds precision for the moment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The epochs of the chrono clocks are unspecified.  But practically you can think of the chrono clocks this way:

1. The epoch of `steady_clock` is the time your application launched plus a signed random offset.  I.e. you can't depend upon the epoch being the same across application launches.  But the epoch will remain stable while an application is running.
2. The epoch of `system_clock` is time since New Years 1970, not counting leap seconds, in the UTC timezone.  Different implementations implement this with varying precision:  libc++ counts microseconds, VS counts 1/10 of microseconds, and gcc counts nanoseconds.
3. `high_resolution_clock` is sometimes a type alias for `steady_clock` and sometimes a type alias for `system_clock`.

For a time stamp in microseconds I recommend first defining this type alias:

```
using time_stamp = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,
                                           std::chrono::microseconds>;
```

Store that, instead of `uint64_t`.  The type safety of this type will save you countless run time errors.  You'll discover your errors at compile time instead.

You can get the current `time_stamp` with:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
time_stamp ts = time_point_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now());
```

Comment: Thanks for great suggestion. Will we see any issues in leap years if we use `steady_clock`?

Comment: Did you mean `system_clock`?!

Comment: @user1950349 - The [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are adjustments made to official time because the Earth's orbit is slightly wobbly (*very* slightly) so sometimes we arrive half a second early. Computers often ignore this, as it's hard enough anyway to calculate time.

Comment: But if you really want to play with leap seconds, here is a library + example on how to do it: http://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html#flightexample2

Comment: Yes I mean `system_clock` sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `system_clock` is counting Unix Time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is nothing but a count of non-leap seconds since 1970 (UTC).  And as coded above, actually that's a count of microseconds.  It knows nothing of days, weeks, months, years or leap years.  If you want to convert into those units, I recommend this date library:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html (which will correctly handle leap years).

Comment: @HowardHinnant I really appreciate you shared this code. It is the first time I see it mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there a recommended way to record timestamps for each event if there are a tremendous amount of events received within a second? (In Windows) I was thinking of just recording the number of ticks from `QueryPerformanceCounter` for each event, and calculating the actual timestamp periodically, once every hour or so, maybe in a different thread. (the application receives events throughout the day, and may need to keep running for over a year)

Comment: Assuming you're using `system_clock`, `ts.time_since_epoch().count()` will give you the integral number of microseconds since the Unix epoch.  This will be a signed 64 bit integral type.

Answer (score 15):

Another possibility for people who couldn't get other solutions to work:

```
uint64_t microseconds_since_epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```